# Adjusting SVG size for rotating globe

Tags: d3.js

In http://bl.ocks.org/ee2dev/71316923a9cd9fb4314a,
you see a rotating globe covering a 250 x 250 area.

How do I need to change my code to set the surrounding SVG to let's say 300 x 250 (= the size of my globe + some horizontal space for the rotating city labels) ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the size of the whole svg is 960x 500, you either need to edit that or rescale the globe in the projection variable

Comment: If I just change the width and height of the svg to 300x200 the globe is not in the svg anymore. But how do I programmatically determine the bounding box of the globe ? Then I can wrap a <g> around it and translate accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to apply a `translate` to your projection.  As per https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#translate you'll see that the projections have a default `translate` suitable for an `svg` of `960` x `500`.  Since your existing example has that size, the default `translate` matches perfectly.

Change your projection code to:

```
var width = 300,
    height = 250;

...

var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
    .scale(125)
    .translate([width/2, height/2])
    .clipAngle(90);
```

Note the inclusion of the `translate` call to the `projection` which changes from the default to the new one based on the size of the `svg`.

Working example at http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/272235d004c7afc8dc68

Comment: Perfect - that was what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! My workaround with getting a bounding box and wrapping a translated <g> around, would be quite a hack...

Comment: p.s. I'll add an additional marker for Melbourne to the globe to give you some recognition for the solution :)

Comment: Nice... that'd be awesome.